# Plot of a linear regression with interactions

Tags: r, regression, interaction

I need to create a plot of the linear regression of the following formula, but I have not understood which is the correct way to do it in R:

```
lm.velocity_vs_Velocity_response = lm(scrd$Velocity~scrd$Velocity_response*scrd$Subject)
```

Where scrd is my dataset which can be downloaded here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3288659/Velocity_vs_Velocity.csv

The dataset, corresponding to an experiment, contains 2 variables (Velocity and Velocity_response) and I want to know if there is a linear correlation between the two. Let's say that the first is the velocity of a car driven under 4 terrains conditions (snow, wood, gravel, and a material inicated with "no sound") and the second is the perceived velocity of the conductor. In the experiment the 4 conditions where repeated twice by 10 participants, who at the end of the experiment had to evaluate the perceived velocities they had whle driving in the conditions. Evaluations where performed on a visual analog scale where 0 = very slow and 10 = very fast.
I have therefore 80 points in my regressions (10 participants * 2 trials * 4 estimate of the velocities). However in the dataset I decided to average the performace of the 2 trials.

The output of the formula I used to make the regression,

```
 summary(lm.velocity_vs_Velocity_response)
```

is

```
Residual standard error: 0.08377 on 20 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.91,  Adjusted R-squared: 0.8245 
F-statistic: 10.64 on 19 and 20 DF,  p-value: 1.085e-06
```

from which I conclude that there is a strong correlation between the two variables (R^2 = 0.91 and p-value < 0.001)

Now, I would like to see the line fitting the linear regression on those data. 
How it is done in R? Which is the correct formula?
Can anyone provide an example of the code in R?

The problem is that using plot I get a mess of points, and I am not able to see a linear trend.

Here I post the first rows of the dataset

```
Subject     Material    Velocity    Velocity_response
Subject1    no_sound    1.41        7.8
Subject1    snow        1.255       4
Subject1    gravel      1.32        5.3
Subject1    wood        1.335       5.4
Subject2    no_sound    1.435       10
Subject2    snow        1.265       1.7
Subject2    gravel      1.3         8.5
Subject2    wood        1.355       5.3
```

Comment: Also, it looks like you have repeated measures. If so, you shouldn't be using lm at all. You should probably be using mixed models.

Comment: lm has a plot() associated with it. You can use plot(lm.velocity_vs.Velocity_response).  Also, surely velocity_response should be on the left side of the model and velocity on the right. It makes no sense to say velocity depends on the response. You might then need ordinal logistic regression.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for answering.

To answer to Peter Flom, of course I have repeated measures. So is it correct or wrong to use lm? I am not an expert of R, nor a statician ;-(, and I would need an help with the code for the mixed models if possible, and if it is wrong to use lm. I have no clue what is ordinal logistic regression nor hpw to perform it...

Apparently Greg Snow agrees in using lm. I am confused. Can someone please clarify this issue? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Your life will be much easier if you run lm like:

```
lm.velocity_vs_Velocity_response <- lm(Velocity~Velocity_response*Subject, data=scrd)
```

Then to explore the relationship and the interaction look at the `Predict.Plot` and `TkPredict` functions in the TeachingDemos package.

Comment: That's certainly true, @Greg. Also, I would suggest a model name that's a little shorter, but that may be personal preference.

Comment: Thanks for the sintax suggestions. Please let me know about the above comment

Comment: @PeterFlom and Luca, I also would suggest a shorter object name, however I tend to err much more on the other end and overuse names like 'fit' and 'tmp', the above is certainly more descriptive.  Using a mixed model would also be a good idea (I did not read close enough to catch the repeated measures).  You can do repeated measures using lm (but you need more terms in your model), but the mixed effects approach is prefered (but does not work with the functions that I mentioned, yet).

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply, but since there are repeated measures is not enough to use the interaction in lm? Morevor, what do ou mean with "you need more terms in your model"? Those are the data that I have. Is it possible for someone to show me the R code to perform the linear regression I need and to plot the graphic with the regression line? Finally, I make notice that the velocities produced in the 2 trials have been averaged.

Comment: @Luca, can you show us some actual data (or simulated data of the correct form), use `dput` so it can be cut and pasted.  Do you have an id variable for the same subject accross the different measures?  with this info we have a better chance of being of help.

Comment: Hi Greg Snow, thanks for providing help, it is very needed. If you open the dataset attached you can see that each subject is identified with a different ID (such as Subject1, Subject2,ecc.). I have not understood how to use dput. However I can show you the results of the questionnaire item on which participants expressed the perceived velocity (i.e. the variable Velocity_response), and the results of the velocity used during the performance (i.e the variable Velocity).You can download them here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3288659/Q4.pdf and here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3288659/Velocity.pdf

Comment: The dataset can be downloaded here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3288659/Velocity_vs_Velocity.csv

Comment: @Luca dropbox is blocked by my current firewall, can you post the first few lines of the data, or use dput on the first few lines.  Otherwise I need to wait until I have time and am not behind the current firewall.

Comment: @GregSnow I put the first lines of the dataset in the question I posted (I updated the very first post, look above). Help! Thanks in advance

Comment: @GregSnow HiGregSnow, have you had the chance to look at my data?

Comment: Looking at the data a mixed model approach will be best for any inference that you want to do.  However, predictions from mixed models is more complex.  I believe that the developement version of lme4 has a predict method.  You could ignore the clustering and fit a linear model for the predictions/plots, the results of the predictions should be similar to the mixed model, but note that the standard errors, tests, and intervals will be wrong, but a plot of the main prediction will be reasonable.

Comment: Dear @GregSnow thanks. I studied the multilevel models, and I arrived to this formula to analyze my data: lme(Velocity_response ~ Velocity*Subject, data=scrd, random= ~1|Subject) Is it correct? However, I do not understand how can I get R^2 and p-values, nor how to plot the graphic with the points and the line fitting the regression. Could you please help me?

Comment: @Luca, you should consult with a local statistician for help with this project.  The understanding needed (by both the statistical consultant and your) to proceed properly far exceeds what can be done in this type of environment.

Comment: Dear @GregSnow I am asking for an help here because in my small department there is not a statician. How can I understand from the output of this formula summary(lme(Velocity_response ~ Velocity, data = scrd, random = ~1 | Subject, data = d)) that the two variables are or not linearly related? I am not able to find in internet this information. Can you enlighten me?